# I'm learning Ruby and I don't clearly understand what :* means in inject(:*)

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a method for calculating the factorial of a number and I found something similar to this in my search.

```
def factorial(number)
  (1..number).inject(:*) || 1
end
```

It works and I understand what the inject function is doing, but I don't clearly understand what the `(:\*)` part really means.

I know it must be a shorthand version of writing `{|num, prod| num*prod}`, but I would love a clear explanation.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`:*` is simply the method name for `*` of the method for `inject` to execute. If you look at the documentation for `inject` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

It states that

> If you specify a symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo. In either case, the result becomes the new value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the return value for the method.

So taken that `inject { |memo, obj| block }`

The following are equal

```
ary = [1,2,3]
ary.inject(:*)
#=> 6
ary.inject { |memo, obj| memo.*(obj) }
#=> 6
```

Comment: So, when you use a symbol, your accumulator is implied, so it really is just a shorter way of saying the same thing.

Comment: Yes, from the documentation the symbol which is just a method name is sent to the `memo` with `obj` as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

## Short explanation

`:*` is a symbol. Symbols are immutable strings. `:*` is like `"*"` except it's immutable.

In ruby, multiplication is a method invocation too. It's equivalent invoking the `.*(second)` method of the first multiplier with the second multiplier as an argument. In fact, you can type `3.*(4)` instead of `3*4`. `3*4` is just syntactic sugar as far as ruby is concerned.

Method invocation in ruby can be invoked by `public_send`ing symbol messages to objects. `3.public_send(:*, 4)` will also work just like `3*4`.

The argument to inject is interpreted as what type of message should be `public_senT`, that is, what method should be invoked from the internals of the inject method.

## Longer explanation

You can think of

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ].inject(:*)
```

as injecting '*' between each adjacent pair of each enumerable object that `inject` is invoked on:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ].inject(:*) == 1 * 2 * 3 * 4
```

Of course `1 * 2 * 3 * 4` is equivalent to going from left to right, and applying :* on your running tally and the next number to get your next tally, and then returning the final tally.

```
module Enumerable
  def inject_asterisk
     tally = first
     rest = slice(1, length - 1)
     rest.each  do |next_num|
       tally = tally * next_num
     end
     return tally
  end
end
[2, 3, 5].inject_asterisk #=> 30
```

You can generalize this by making the operation that combines the `tally` and `next_number` to get your next `tally` an argument function. Blocks in ruby serve basically as argument functions that always have a reserved spot.

```
module Enumerable
  def inject_block(&block)
     tally = first
     rest = slice(1, length - 1)
     rest.each  do |next_num|
       tally = block.call(tally, next_num)
     end
     return tally
  end
end
[2, 3, 5].inject_block {|tally, next_num| tally + next_num } #=> 10
```

If your block is always going to be of the form

```
{|tally, next_num| tally.method_of_tally(next_num) }
```

as it is in this case (remember `tally + next_num` <==> `tally.+(next_num)` <==> `tally.public_send(:+,next_num)`, you can decide to only pass `:method_of_tally` as the argument and imply the block.

```
 module Enumerable
  def my_inject(method_of_tally_symbol, &block)

     if method_of_tally_symbol
        block = Proc.new  { |tally, next_num| 
               tally.public_send(method_of_tally_symbol, next_num) 
               }
     end
     
     tally = first
     rest = slice(1, length - 1)
     rest.each  do |next_num|
       tally = block.call(tally, next_num)
     end
     return tally
  end
end
[2, 3, 5].my_inject(:+) #=> 10
```

It's all about extracting repeated patterns into reusable components so that you don't have to type as much.

Answer (score 0):

It means `symbol to proc` and it's a shortcut. Typically you would write something like

```
array.map { |e| e.join }
```

with symbol to proc, the shorthand would be

```
array.map(&:join)
```

`inject` and `reduce` are similar, but you don't need the `&` in those cases

For example, if you have an array of numbers called `numbers`

To sum the numbers, you could do

```
numbers.inject(&:+)
```

or you could leave off the ampersand

```
numbers.inject(:+)
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with `Symbol#to_proc`. `Enumerable#inject` simply takes the name of the method to use as a `Symbol`, just like, say, `attr_accessor` or `define_method` or `send`.

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Inject is a method on enumerable that combines the elements of said enumerable using a symbol (as in your case) or a block (as in your proposed longhand).

For example:

`(5..10).reduce(:*)` is equivalent to `(5..10).inject { |prod, n| prod + n }`